# CA Siteminder SSO integration wth Microsoft OWA?

Tags: outlook-web-app

Is it possible to setup CA Siteminder SSO to frontend Outlook Web Access?

Currently, our OWA is setup to AD authentication but we primarily use CA SSO from a central portal and thus would like to make the authentication process seemless to the end user.

Any online references or comments with experience to this question would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is an add on module available for SiteMinder that supports integration with OWA. Inquire with CA support and they can direct you the correct location for the component